# How to make the seal on swimming goggles work again

Tags: swimming

I use Aquasphere goggles for swimming and when they are new they seal really well. I swim for at least 60 minutes and if I leave them alone, my eyes stay dry for the whole session.

However, when the goggles are 3 months old, they start to leak. I guess the problem is that the gasket gets dirty as the goggles age. Can anyone suggest a cleaning product to clean the gasket and restore it to its slightly sticky, as new state so the goggles seal like new again. Or do I just have to buy (more) new goggles?

Comment: How much were the goggles? Are they even worth refurbishing if brand new is afforadable?

Comment: They cost about £20 and last in good condition about 3 months. To me, that's costly enough to look for something to double their useful life.

Answer (score 1):

I use Aquasphere, and mine typically last around 2 years. My kids swim competitively and theirs will last at least a year - usually for them it's the strap or nose-piece that gives way first, not the seal.

Gaskets being dirty should not be an issue - that isn't what should seal them. I think your problem is you aren't tightening them enough. They should be held on your face so strongly that dirt is irrelevant. I know I can dive in with mine on (a racing dive) and they will not come off.

So try tightening up the strap a fair bit.

If you are concerned about the gasket, mild dish soap will be fine.

Comment: Same. I used Tyr and Speedo goggles, but usually got at least a season of year round use before replacing either strap or nosepiece. To clean, I usually chucked them in the dishwasher on a short cycle.

Comment: Try Sweedish goggles, very basic, no gasket (some fancier versions have them), cheap, last forever. Mine has been with me for over 10 years. Spit rub to anti-fog, light soap & water wash when done & then put in a soft bag. For restoring softness of the gaskets, if they're silicone, dip them in a solution of hot (not boiling but not warm) water and a few drops of dish detergent. Leave in until the water is just slightly warm. Take them out & clean with warm water. Preferrably, the water is distilled or soft water.